# Pip install package from private github repo in google cloud appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip, gcloud

I am using google cloud appengine and deploying with `gcloud app deploy` and a standard `app.yaml` file. My requirements.txt file has one private package that is fetched from github (`git+ssh://git@github.com/...git`). This install works locally, but when I run the deploy I get

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This suggests there is no ssh key when installing. Reading docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies) it appears that this just isn't an option???

```
Dependencies are installed in a Cloud Build environment that does not provide access to SSH keys. Packages hosted on repositories that require SSH-based authentication must be copied into your project directory and uploaded alongside your project's code using the pip package manager.
```

To me this seems severely not-optimal - the whole point of factoring out code into a package was to be able to avoid duplication in repos. Now, if I want to use appengine, you're telling me this not possible?

Is there really no workaround?

Answer (score 2):

See:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#private_dependencies

The App Engine service does not (and should not) have access to your **private** repo.

One alternative (that you don't want) is to upload your public key to the App Engine service.

The other -- as documented -- is that you must provide the content of your private repo to the service as part of your upload.

Comment: why dont i want to upload public key to app engine service

Comment: You may want to do this but, I think, it's preferable not to do so. Giving the service, your GitHub token(s), compounds the trust you place in Google and increases your need to control the distribution of your keys. Such tokens are bearer tokens and so anyone|thing that has them it able to operate on your behalf. It's best to keep them as locked down as possible. As it is, App Engine does not permit this functionality, so the question is moot.

Comment: so literally the only option i have is to upload the private package code with the project? is there any benefit to factoring things out into shared package?

Comment: If your package is shared then you benefit from not duplicating the sources and managing changes to this package independently with git. If your package were public, App Engine would not need to authenticate and so the challenge would not arise. Because you want to use a private shared repository, you must provide App Engine with the sources that it is otherwise not-authenticated to obtain. You have an option that is secure and enables you to manage a private shared package and deploy apps to App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the same issue, deploying on gcloud a python project that contains in its requirements.txt some private repositories. As @DazWilkin wrote already, there's no way to deploy it like you do normally.

One option would be to create a docker image of the whole project and its dependencies, save it into the gcloud docker registry and then pull it into the App Engine instance.

Comment: If a custom Docker image is involved perhaps it is better to use Google Cloud Run instead of App Engine.

Comment: Yes @mac13k, same recommendation we got from the google partners